# Need help about grails&acegi

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

refer to http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Basic+Tutorial

if I need to custom field,for example i need gender,age,etc.
How to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the generated User class to meet your requirements. BTW: the acegi plugin is superseeded by spring-security-core/spring-security-ui.

Answer (score 0):

Change the User domain class to add the fields you want, and then generate your manager files. Also, if you already have a User domain class that you want to use, you can do `grails create-auth-domains DummyUser Role Requestmap`. The generated Role domain will be looking at the DummyUser, but change

`static hasMany = [people: DummyUser]` to

`static hasMany = [people: User]`

and you're all set.